# Postgres LTREE: How to do recursive for only a few specific rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchy, postgresql-9.5, ltree

My actual use case is similar to how comment threads work on Reddit for example. If I do the query based on the LTREE path for the post itself, then it works fine and brings all the child comments. But if I do the query on `permalink` of a nested child comment, then I want it to return both the parent post and also all the children from that child comment onwards.

My actual query is fairly complex but I am able to demonstrate the issue with this simple example.

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (node_path ltree,score INTEGER);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top',150);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Science',23);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Science.Astronomy',5);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Science.Astronomy.Astrophysics',43);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Science.Astronomy.Cosmology',23);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Hobbies',16);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Hobbies.Amateurs_Astronomy',2);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Collections',65);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures',88);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy',36);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Stars',97);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Galaxies',58);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Astronauts',6);
INSERT INTO nodes VALUES ('Top.Dislikes',28);
CREATE INDEX ON nodes (score);
CREATE INDEX ON nodes USING GIST (node_path);
CREATE INDEX ON nodes USING BTREE (node_path);
```

I need to query the data such that `Top.Science` and `Top.Collections` nodes are present plus I also want all the nodes which are or are descendants of the path `*.Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.*`. I basically want it to not do recursion for the top 2 rows and do it for the children ones.

The correct output I want is:

```
                   node_path                   | score | sort_path 
-----------------------------------------------+-------+-----------
 Top.Science                                   |    23 | {1}
 Top.Collections                               |    65 | {2}
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy            |    36 | {2,2}
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Astronauts |     6 | {2,2,1}
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Galaxies   |    58 | {2,2,2}
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Stars      |    97 | {2,2,3}
```

The first query I tried was:

```
with recursive
t as (select * from nodes where node_path = ANY('{Top.Science,Top.Collections}') OR node_path ~ '*.Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.*'::lquery),
l as (select nlevel(node_path) n from t order by n limit 1),
base as (
  select node_path, score, 
         array[row_number() over (order by score ASC, node_path)] as sort_path
    from t, l 
   where nlevel(node_path) = l.n
  union all
  select c.node_path, c.score, 
         p.sort_path||row_number() over (order by c.score ASC, c.node_path)
    from base p
    join t c 
      on subpath(c.node_path, 0, -1) = p.node_path
)
select * from base order by sort_path;
```

This gives me only the following data:

```
    node_path    | score | sort_path 
-----------------+-------+-----------
 Top.Science     |    23 | {1}
 Top.Collections |    65 | {2}
(2 rows)
```

I understand the `=` in the `subpath(c.node_path, 0, -1) = p.node_path` is what causes only these 2 rows to be returned.

So I changed the `=` to `<@` as follows:

```
with recursive
t as (select * from nodes where node_path = ANY('{Top.Science,Top.Collections}') OR node_path ~ '*.Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.*'::lquery),
l as (select nlevel(node_path) n from t order by n limit 1),
base as (
  select node_path, score, 
         array[row_number() over (order by score ASC, node_path)] as sort_path
    from t, l 
   where nlevel(node_path) = l.n
  union all
  select c.node_path, c.score, 
         p.sort_path||row_number() over (order by c.score ASC, c.node_path)
    from base p
    join t c 
      on subpath(c.node_path, 0, -1) <@ p.node_path
)
select * from base order by sort_path;
```

This gives me the following:

```
                   node_path                   | score | sort_path 
-----------------------------------------------+-------+-----------
 Top.Science                                   |    23 | {1}
 Top.Collections                               |    65 | {2}
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Astronauts |     6 | {2,1}
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy            |    36 | {2,2}
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Astronauts |     6 | {2,2,1}
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Galaxies   |    58 | {2,2,2}
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Stars      |    97 | {2,2,3}
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Galaxies   |    58 | {2,3}
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Stars      |    97 | {2,4}
(9 rows)
```

While now all the rows are there, the `children` rows are repeated. I think it's due to the recursion but I am having a hard time understanding why and how to fix it.

Note that if I remove the `WHERE` for the top 2 rows and only query for the children ones, then it gives me the children as I expect:

```
with recursive
t as (select * from nodes where node_path ~ '*.Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.*'::lquery),
l as (select nlevel(node_path) n from t order by n limit 1),
base as (
  select node_path, score, 
         array[row_number() over (order by score ASC, node_path)] as sort_path
    from t, l 
   where nlevel(node_path) = l.n
  union all
  select c.node_path, c.score, 
         p.sort_path||row_number() over (order by c.score ASC, c.node_path)
    from base p
    join t c 
      on subpath(c.node_path, 0, -1) = p.node_path
)
select * from base order by sort_path;
```

One solution I do have in mind is to query the top 2 rows separately, query the children separately, then `UNION` then together. However, that seems unnecessarily complicated.

**EDIT:** My question seems similar to how to get the tree where some of the rows are missing. For example, how to get the tree of the following data:

```
                   node_path                   | score 
-----------------------------------------------+-------
 Top.Science                                   |    23 
 Top.Collections                               |    65 
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy            |    36 
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Astronauts |     6 
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Galaxies   |    58 
 Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Stars      |    97
```

Notice how the `Top.Collections.Pictures` path is missing in this.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `UNION ALL` of two queries: one for the two elements, and a recursive query.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes, I mention that towards the end of my question that I do have that possible solution. But it seems wasteful to do it separately because in my real query, the combination of all the rows which are being fed into the recursive thing are coming from `JOIN` of another table. So it seems wasteful to do those JOINs on multiple queries separately. Is there no way of being able to sort multiple rows where some of the rows may not be children of others?

Comment: Perhaps a CTE could be the solution? `WITH sthg AS (/* expensive query */) SELECT /* query on sthg */ UNION ALL SELECT /* query on sthg */`

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't produce the exact output described in the original post; however, it demonstrates an approach that can be used to selectively recurse:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
search_paths(search_path, get_descendents) AS (
  VALUES ('Top.Science'::lquery, false),
         ('Top.Collections'::lquery, false),
         ('*.Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.*'::lquery, true)),
cte AS (SELECT n.*,
               p.get_descendents,
               array[row_number() OVER (ORDER BY nlevel(n.node_path), n.score, n.node_path)] AS sort_path
          FROM nodes n
          JOIN search_paths p
            ON n.node_path ~ p.search_path
        UNION ALL
        SELECT n.*,
               cte.get_descendents,
               cte.sort_path || array[row_number() OVER (ORDER BY nlevel(n.node_path), n.score, n.node_path)] AS sort_path
          FROM cte
          JOIN nodes n
            ON cte.get_descendents AND
               cte.node_path @> n.node_path AND
               cte.node_path <> n.node_path),
distinct_node_paths AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (cte.node_path) cte.*
    FROM cte
    ORDER BY cte.node_path, cte.sort_path)
SELECT dnp.node_path, dnp.score, dnp.sort_path
  FROM distinct_node_paths dnp
  ORDER BY dnp.sort_path;
```

Having both `.*` at the end of `search_path` and `get_descendents` set to `true` is redundant (either is sufficient to get the descendents).